# How to start quartz scheduler 2.2.1?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

On the [quartz website](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start) they say : `The main Quartz library is named quartz-all-xxx.jar (where xxx is a version number)`

I downloaded the [latest release 2.2](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/destination?name=quartz-2.2.1-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=quartz-2.2.1-distribution.tar.gz)

Here are all the jars in the `lib` folder

[image]

I looked everywhere but could not find the `quartz-all-xxx.jar`

---

Anyway i added all these jars from the above folder to the class path . And copy pasted their [sample](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02) code . However Eclipse did not recognize `Job` , `withIdentity` , `simpleSchedule` classes and methods

[image]

Comment: There is no quartz-all library . all libraries that you need to add are in the lib

Comment: right thats what i figured , did i added the correct jars ? are there any additional jars i need to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the sample closely:

```
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)

Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
```

They don't construct the jobs and triggers with `new`, they use factory functions with static imports:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
```

quartz-all-xxx.jar used to be a single jar with all the dependencies (log4j, etc) included. This seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: Thank you. I have follow up question . Why does   not Eclipse prompt to import these classes when i hover mouse over the `newJob` and `newTrigger` . Also, what should i import for `simpleSchedule `

Comment: Eclipse does not look up possible static imports for performance reasons, I think. To use simpleSchedule import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;